# How do I handle False/Empty query's in a ASP.net Web forms App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, webforms

I am building a web forms app in Visual Studio and have a number of button functions to allow the user to add, alter and delete from my database.

And all the functions work the way they are intended ***up until a user enters the wrong information or doesn't enter anything***

Here is the error I get

[image]

I have done some research myself but I am still not sure how to fix it, And would love some help

Here is the code in question

```
   public partial class DeleteCharacters : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private MarvelModelContext context = new MarvelModelContext();

        protected void btnDeleteId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
            string Sname = SNameT.Text;
            Character CRead = context.Character.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CharacterId == id && c.Superhero == Sname);
            context.Character.Remove(CRead);//Error Pops up here 

            context.SaveChanges();

            //Clear Feilds
            txtId.Text = "";
            SNameT.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are using FirstOrDefault. Check to see if the value is null before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MKS suggested you must check for null if you are using [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx). This returns `null` if it can't find a match in your lambda expression. So, the updated method should look like this.

```
 public partial class DeleteCharacters : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private MarvelModelContext context = new MarvelModelContext();

    protected void btnDeleteId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
        string Sname = SNameT.Text;
        Character CRead = context.Character.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CharacterId == id && c.Superhero == Sname);

        if(CRead != null) // added this condition
        {
            context.Character.Remove(CRead);

            context.SaveChanges();

            //Clear Feilds
            txtId.Text = "";
            SNameT.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```